# Jersey vs RestEasy - JAX-RS XML collection root element name change

Tags: java, xml, jersey, jax-rs, resteasy

I have the following Jax-RS end-point:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "foobar")
public class Foobar {}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Object getFoobars() {
    return new GenericEntity<List<FooBar>>(service.getFooBars());
}
```

Using Jersey 1.x, it used to return:

```
<foobars>
  <foobar>...</foobar>
  <foobar>...</foobar>
</foobars>
```

Now that I use RestEasy, it returns:

```
<collection>
  <foobar>...</foobar>
  <foobar>...</foobar>
</collection>
```

How can I control the **root name** of a returned `GenericEntity<List<X>>` in Jax-RS (using Rest-Easy)?

*Please note that I also return Json format and I need to keep the API backward-compatible (for exemple the root element is an array in Json and should stay the same)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution myself after digging a bit in the RestEasy source code. You just have to add the `@Wrapped(element="___")` annotation to the method:

```
import org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.providers.jaxb.Wrapped;

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Wrapped(element = "foobars")
public Object getFoobars() {
    return new GenericEntity<List<FooBar>>(service.getFooBars());
}
```

Works correctly for XML and properly ignored for JSON.